# Launching driver programmatically from within Karate docker container

Tags: docker, selenium-chromedriver, karate

I've a test where I need to log-in as two different users at the same time. I've used https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core/#java-api for guidance in launching the second chrome instance and have everything working as expected locally, but I hit an issue when I try running it in Git Actions using the karatelabs/karate-chrome docker image.

I've been trying to dig in and see what needs to be set when initialising the Driver instance as you can see from an example of the code below, but I'm struggling to mimic what gets set behind the scenes. Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Paul

```
import com.intuit.karate.driver.Driver;

public class SecondChromeInstance
{
    public static void Test(boolean running_in_ci)
    {
        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        options.put("type", "chrome");
        if (running_in_ci)
        {
            options.put("host", "host.docker.internal");
            options.put("port", 9222);
        }
        Driver driver = Driver.start(options);
    }     
}
```

Called from my feature file as follows...

```
* def SecondChromeInstance = Java.type('utilities.SecondChromeInstance')
* SecondChromeInstance.Test(running_in_ci)
```

Which gives the following error in the logs...

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: driver config / start failed: http call failed after 1 milliseconds for url: http://host.docker.internal:9222/json
java.net.UnknownHostException: host.docker.internal, options: {port=9222, host=host.docker.internal, type=chrome}
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions.start(DriverOptions.java:323)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.Driver.start(Driver.java:56)
- utilities.SecondChromeInstance.Test(SecondChromeInstance.java:48)
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

**Update - working example.**

Within the scenario, I retrieve the following from the default driver instance:

```
 * def opt = driver.getOptions()
 * def port = opt.port
 * def host = opt.host
 * def target = opt.options.get("target")
```

And then pass them into my java class, configuring the driver instance as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.put("type", "chrome");
options.put("addOptions", Arrays.asList("--remote-allow-origins=*"));
        
if (runningInCI)
{
    options.put("port", port);
    options.put("start", false);
    options.put("host", host);
    options.put("showDriverLog", true);
    options.put("target", target);
    options.put("docker", "ptrthomas/karate-chrome");
}

Driver driver = Driver.start(options);
try
{
    driver.setUrl(XXX);
    ...
}
finally
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

Only downside that I can see is that the karate report that gets generated in CI only captures video of the last driver instance, but I can live with that. Last thing I'm interested in trying to do is to somehow print statements from within the java instance so that it's logged to the report.

Hopefully this helps someone else!

Comment: I remember `host.docker.internal` only works on a mac - but looks like some new hacks are possible: https://medium.com/@TimvanBaarsen/how-to-connect-to-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container-112b4c71bc66

Comment: Separate to that, am I generally on the right path @peter-thomas? Looking at your DriverOptions.java class, these a whole host of options that can be set, such as useDockerHost.

Comment: I think yes, but see if this thread helps: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2193